# Onclick causes Server Connection Reset in Joomla 3.3.6

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have been developing a Joomla website locally on MAMP 3.2x and just yesterday I migrated it to the clients server. It is running CentOS 6.5 with Apache 2.2.xx (standard CentOS Package). I have installed php5.5 & php5.5-fpm, along with MySQL etc.

The site is working absolutely fine, except for 1 little issue, which I have narrowed down to the word "Onclick"

If any article or module or content, somewhere includes the word "onclick", as soon as I click Save, Save Close, Cancel, etc, I get a Server Dropped Connection Error.

The weird thing is if its "Onclic" or "Onclik" or anyother variation, then its fine. But somehow "onclick" causes it to fail.

- Its not a POST Size issue, just a simple line will do it.
- I have tried
  Chrome, Safari and Firefox.
- I have checked my server logs, Apache,
  FPM & MySql. No errors pertaining to this
- Also tried disabling fpm and switching to default php
- switched to php 5.6 but still the same issue

The only clue I have is this

`POST http://example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&layout=edit&id=224 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET core.js:1 
 Joomla.submitform -> core.js:1
 Joomla.submitbutton-> index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=224:534 
 onclick-> index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=224:502`

--Update--
The issue only happens if onclick is part of a html tag. It seems the HTML filtering portion of Joomla is the culprit, even though its set to No Filtering for SuperAdmins

the bare minimujm text required for this issue to show up is

```
< onclick= >
```

The following variations are fine

```
< onclick
< onclick=
< onclick >
```

Help please!!

Comment: Please dont edit my post. I meant what I wrote. I have clarified further incase of confusions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a restrictive firewall blocking the POST. Gonna have to move my listeners to the JS files and remove the onclick tags.